# Tomato firmware ver 1.28: A.P. mode security choices

Tags: tomato

Briefly, I was using Tomato ver 1.28 on my Linksys for over a year at my old house. Think it was set to AP mode and using WPA2. New house owner won't allow connect to main wireless router so I have to discover config settings that work. Simply want to wire my pc to the tomato router/access point.

Main question is if anyone knows if I can use security choices other than WPA2 when attempting AP mode because I get an error in tomato ver 1.28. Otherwise, some people think I really want WET mode or "WET bridge" mode but I'm sure I was not using either previously.

Believe I want dhcp turned off under Basic>LAN settings, but not sure if I want to set the tomato router's IP to 192.168.1.2. Think I can get the rest.

Comment: Use your current router to connect to the existing network